# How to create a series of integers in a dataframe only when there are no NaNs, and integers increasing by 1 unit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that look like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.5, 1.2, 2.7, 3.8, NaN, NaN, 0.1, 0.7, 2.3, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.01, 0.4, 1.5, 2.8, 4.5, 5.6, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN])
```

The extra column I need to create should look like this:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([NaN, NaN, NaN, 1, 1, 1, 1, NaN, NaN, 2, 2, 2, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN])
```

Basically, when there are NaNs, the integer remains the same, and when not a NaN is found it should increment by 1 unit and be constant until another NaN is found.

Is there an elegant way to do this without going through every row individually? My dataframe is very large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider this input data

```
NaN = np.nan
data = pd.DataFrame(
    [NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.5, 1.2, 2.7, 3.8, NaN, NaN, 0.1, 0.7, 2.3, NaN, NaN, 
     NaN, NaN, NaN, 0.01, 0.4, 1.5, 2.8, 4.5, 5.6, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN])
```

So the idea is to first create a Boolean column where it is not nan with `notna`.

```
m = data[0].notna()
```

Now, you can get the `diff` on this Boolean column to get `True` when it change from True to False or vice-versa. Keep the `True` only when it changes when `notna` with `&m`. Use `cumsum` to get the incremental integer and then `where` with the Boolean mask `m` to replace by NaN where it was Nan originally. So in one liner:

```
data['res'] = (m.diff()&m).cumsum().where(m)
print(data)
       0  res
0    NaN  NaN
1    NaN  NaN
2    NaN  NaN
3   0.50  1.0
4   1.20  1.0
5   2.70  1.0
6   3.80  1.0
7    NaN  NaN
8    NaN  NaN
9   0.10  2.0
10  0.70  2.0
11  2.30  2.0
12   NaN  NaN
13   NaN  NaN
...
```